# If I integrate $\int_1^{-1} x^{-2} \,dx =-2$ what is the significance of this answer?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If I integrate $\int_1^{-1} x^{-2} \,dx$ using normal integration methods (so without limits) the answer is $-2$. What is the significance of this answer? (Like what does it mean?)
Thanks in advance

Comment: The significance is it's wrong.

Comment: but for $x=0$ there is a pol for $$y=x^{-2}$$

Comment: make sense using hadamard finite part method :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything. The integral does not converge there so the theorem that allows you to compute an integral as the difference of the anti derivatives does not apply and the result you get is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

By definition: $\int_{-1}^{1} x^{-2} \,dx$ is convergent iff $\int_{-1}^{0} x^{-2} \,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1} x^{-2} \,dx$ are convergent.

But  $\int_{-1}^{0} x^{-2} \,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1} x^{-2} \,dx$ are divergent.